# How can I use application-scoped resources when my application builds as 'Page' and not 'Application Definition'?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use a custom Main method in my WPF application.

To do that, I need to build the application XAML file as a Page, instead of an application definition :

[image]

When I try to define a style as a resource :

```
<Application
    x:Class="MyProgram.Program"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and I try to use that style in my window :

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Style="{StaticResource WindowStyle}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"/>
```

even though the designer works fine, when I try and run the program, it does not end well. I get an exception, the inner exception which reads `{"Cannot find resource named 'WindowStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."}`

When the Build Action on the program is `ApplicationDefinition`, everything goes fine. But like I said, when I set it as `Page` ( which I need to for the sake of being able to define a custom main method ), I can't use the styles defined in the application resources.

Why is that? Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `Main()` method into a custom class, and in `Project Properties -> Application` set `Startup object` to your custom class. Your new `Main()` method should get called upon startup and you don't have to build `App.xaml` as Page, which should solve the problems with resource resolution.

Comment: Defined class with `Main` method does not appear within the list of startup objects.

Comment: Strange. I suggest trying it in a test solution and see if that works. Are you sure your `Main` definition is correct? It should be `[STAThread] public static void Main(string[] args) { ... }`. You can also try inserting the setting manually into your `csproj` file, like this: 
`<PropertyGroup><StartupObject>Namespace.Class</StartupObject></PropertyGroup>`

Comment: Restarted and it worked. This is the most straightforward, and most "correct" answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any specific reason that you are writing your styles in main Application XAML. If you want you can create your style under resource dictionaries in a separate file and merge that style at any place where you want.

For example:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow.Styles"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And merge the "WindowStyle" in the file where you want to use. Let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: The big reason was that I wanted to avoid having to merge dictionaries. I wanted the styles to be accessible application wide without needing to reference them in other places. But my research after posting this question has lead me to a similar conclusion - define the style within a `ResourceDictionary`, then reference that resource dictionary within the `Foo.Resources` of the control that needs to use the style.

Comment: It's not working. I implemented the style into a resource dictionary, but I'm still getting the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's one of those that you just want to smash your head into your keyboard.

I was neglecting to call `App.InitializeComponent( );` That resolves the entire issue.